# Double Integration using polar coordinates

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

so the question I was trying to answer was, find the volume of the solid bounded above by the ellipsoid of revolution

$$b^2 x^2 + b^2 y^2 + a^2 z^2 = a^2 b^2,$$

below by the x-y plane

and on the sides by the cylinder $$x^2 + y^2 - ay = 0$$

I converted this into polar coordinates and got two possible double integrals to get my answer. The second one got me the correct answer, the first one got me the wrong answer. Could someone please help me figure out why the first integral calculates the wrong answer? It's been driving me mad for a day now!

Here is the one that gave me an incorrect answer (https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZ8GI.jpg)

and Here is the one that gave me the correct answer. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjQMr.jpg)

In the first one I tried to exploit the symmetry, the volume is the volume above the first quadrant in the xy plane multiplied by two.

Help would be very much appreciated. I guess I'll need to rack up some reputation points and put a bounty on this.. Not getting anywhere by myself

Comment: I think that your "wrong" answer is actually correct.

Comment: If the first method is correct then I'm doubly confused as to why the second one isn't! I'm pretty sure the second one is correct, I've assumed even less and it matches the answer in the back of my textbook

Comment: Never trust blindly in textbook answers.

Comment: Sure but the fact that I've found a solid method that matches the textbook answer surely indicates that the textbook answer is correct and my first one is wrong?

Comment: What "solid" method?

Comment: Converting the integral into polar coordinates and summing from 0 to pi instead of 0 to pi/2.

Comment: Your "solid" method does not respect the symmetry. With $|\dot{}|$ the symmetry is respected.

Comment: Hey Martin, is the fact that wolframalpha and symbolab calculated the integral incorrectly indicate an issue with their programming? Or should I have written it in a different way to begin with?

Comment: Problems like this are already know: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11517/computer-algebra-errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible problem: doing the inner integral:
$$\int_0^{a\sin\theta}br\sqrt{1 - r^2/a^2}\,dr = -\frac{b}{3a}(a^2 - r^2)^{3/2}\Big\vert_{r = 0}^{r = a\sin\theta} = \frac{a^2b}3(1 - |\cos^3\theta|)$$
and the $|\dot{}|$ is essential.

EDIT: The *symmetry* is true. For $\theta\in[0,\pi/2]$ we have $|\cos\theta| = \cos\theta$ and:
$$
\int_0^\pi\frac{a^2b}3(1 - |\cos^3\theta|)\,d\theta =
2\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{a^2b}3(1 - |\cos^3\theta|)\,d\theta =
2\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{a^2b}3(1 - \cos^3\theta)\,d\theta\ne
\int_0^{\pi}\frac{a^2b}3(1 - \cos^3\theta)\,d\theta.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I don't think the issue is with calculation of the integral itself, I've double checked that with symbolab and wolframalpha. Maybe I've misunderstood what you've said?

Comment: The *values* of your integrals are correct. Only one is the *volume*. You can check that with the $|\dot{}|$ you have $\int_0^\pi = 2 \int_0^{\pi/2}$.

Comment: I don't really understand, I have worked through the integral making sure im using |cos^3(theta)| and not cos^3(theta), in neither case do I get your equation

Comment: @Ravi, see my edit.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you so much, I get it now, so both me and the textbook got flummoxed here, one last question, is |.| necessary because we have 

$$(a-r^2)^(3/2)$$

Specifically the ^3/2 ensuring that the term will always be positive?

Comment: @Ravi, the term will always be positive because is the *positive square root* of $(\cdots)^3$.

Answer (score 0):

If you look to the cylinder equation you'll see that it is shifted about $\frac{2}{a}$ in the $y$-axis, so there is no symmetry, but if it was centered in the origin, like the ellipsoid, the first method would work.

Comment: but there is symmetry about the y-axis for that equation because 
$$(-x)^2 + y^2 - ay = x^2 + y^2 - ay = 0$$

Comment: There is symmetry about the y axis but not x, hence integration on a quarter turn doesn't work.